# Как в java проверить наличие базы данных (Postgresql) с определенным именем?

Tags: java, postgresql

Перед выполнением запроса на создание базы данных в PostgreSQL, хотелось бы проверить создана ли она уже, чтобы не выполнять запрос, если она уже там есть. PostgreSQL нет синтаксиса, чтобы указать в запросе, типа IS NOT Exist для создания базы данных, так можно сделать только с таблицами.

Comment: Сделать запрос в pg_database. См. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-database.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логика такая:

```
Connection connection = null;
boolean haveBase = false;
try{
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("настройки подключения");
    haveBase = true;
}(Exception e){
//нет подключения
   haveBase = false;
}
if (!haveBase){
  //содавать базу тут
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, логика понятна, но можно ли сделать отдельный метод или как-то в запросе провернуть это все, можно ли так сделать?

Comment: @ВарданМатевосян Конечно можете сделать это в методе, в запросе нельзя такое сделать

Comment: Спасибо, понял)